# Communication errors while trying to replicate mongodb

Tags: mongodb, azure, replication, database-replication, ubuntu-14.04

I'm trying to replicate my mongodb database, I've crated 2 VM on my windows azure account.
both of them are Ubuntu 14.04.
I've opened 27017 port on both of them, and installed mongodb latest version.
I started mongo by using

```
mongod --port 27017 --dbpath /data/datadrive --replSet rs0
```

on both machines, and added the other member by using

> rs.add("INTERNAL IP ADDRESS:27017")

I kept getting an error that I have two primaries, I was reading in one of the forums
that it happened because of the bind_ip configuration in /etc/mongodb.conf 
so I changed the bind_ip to other Vm private net ip on both VM's
and while trying to add the server member I've got the following errors.

On the "primary" side:

```
[rsMgr] not electing self, 100.79.138.73:27017 would veto with 'I don't think reptester1:27017 is electable'
[rsHealthPoll] replset info 100.79.138.73:27017 thinks that we are down
[rsHealthPoll] replset info 100.79.138.73:27017 thinks that we are down
```

and on the "secondary" side:

```
[rsHealthPoll] getaddrinfo("reptester1") failed: Name or service not known
[rsHealthPoll] couldn't connect to reptester1:27017: couldn't connect to server reptester1:27017 (0.0.0.0) failed, address resolved to 0.0.0.0
[rsHealthPoll] replset info reptester1:27017 just heartbeated us, but our heartbeat failed: , not changing state
[rsHealthPoll] getaddrinfo("reptester1") failed: Name or service not known
```

Any ideas what am I doing wrong?

Comment: It looks like you didn't follow the instructions. Try following the [basic replica set setup tutorial](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/deploy-replica-set-for-testing/). There might be other network problems, but the way you described setting up the set is not right either.

Answer (score 0):

Can you debug following things  -

1. Telnet the mongo port from both machine (i.e Primary and Secondary) to each other. Check, whether it's working or not.
2. I believe, in replica configuration you are using rs.add("reptester2") to add secondary server. Please check your /etc/hosts file, ipaddress <-> hosts mapping should present in both primary and secondary machine.
3. If you are using bind_ip in both primary and secondary configuration. then use that ip address in your hosts (/etc/hosts) file or rs.add("IP Address"). Please don't use local ip address like 127.0.0.1.

Comment: Hey there, While trying to telent the mongo I got
telnet: could not resolve 23.101.184.130:27017/telnet: Name or service not known

and the hosts file have only localhost configuration on both VM's.

and what should i use in the bind_ip? i've tried to put 0.0.0.0 there and i still got the same error

Comment: In question, you have mentioned, you are using internal IP address. Can you telnet with internal ip address on both machine. If you still get the same error, then please make sure your mongo port is accessible to each other.

Answer (score 0):

It was a dns prob, Because member[0] name was Reptest1, The secondary server resolve the address ad reptest, instead of the ip address or the dns address. I've edit the Member Host Address. and they started to connect one each other.
I did it by using

```
$conf = rs.conf()
$conf.members[0].host = "mongo.cloudapp.net:27017"
rs.reconfig($conf)
```